# When using redis for sharing session,To save the object in the session When get is empty,but save String is normal

Tags: java, tomcat, redis

tomcat context.conf:

```
<Valve className="com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionHandlerValve"/>       
<Manager className="com.radiadesign.catalina.session.RedisSessionManager"
host="localhost" 
port="6379"
database="0" 
maxInactiveInterval="-1"/>
```

use jar:
   jedis-2.2.0.jar  commons-pool-1.6.jar  commons-pool2-2.0.jar   tomcat-redis-session-manager-1.2-tomcat-7-java-7.jar

Comment: need to implement java.io.Serializable.Has been solved

Answer (score 0):

Redis only supports a certain types of simple data structurs(i.e string, byte, integer, list, set etc.) One way of save object in Redis is to serializethe object and store it as byte array.

Comment: I put objects in the session, then put the session object of redis, but access to the object in the session is empty, can save string, what's the other way to achieve it, don't want to change the original program